# Стиль кода

Tags: php

Есть два аналогичных варианта:

```
$handle = fopen("$file.txt", 'w'));   // 1  
$handle = fopen("./$file.txt", 'w')); // 2
```

Кроме стиля написания и личных предпочтений, есть ли практическая разница в применение обоих вариантов?
В документации ответ не нашёл(если он там есть).

P.s. Лично я предпочитаю второй вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разница в указании пути, один указывается относительно корневой директории, а второй относительно текущего файла.

Comment: от корневой директории будет "/filepath". В моём случае оба от текущей директории.

Comment: Извиняюсь, вы правы про относительный и абсолютный пути. Но минус оставлю так как ничего нового не сказано.

Comment: Не совсем так :)
В первом случае файл будет искаться в каталогах, указанных в переменной include_path в php.ini (по умолчанию ".;/path/to/php/pear") - т.е. текущий каталог тоже входит

Comment: @kolu4iy Вы конечно правы, про относительный путь только вопрос про другое был.
[Из доков][1]:
Однако, более эффективно использовать include './file', чем заставлять PHP каждый раз проверять текущую директорию при подключении каждого файла.   

Другими словами, это даёт небольшое ускорение в высоко-нагруженных проектах.


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/ini.core.php#ini.include-path

Answer (score 4):

А при чём тут "стиль кода"?  Оба варианта абсолютно одинаковы..  И оба неправильны.. :)

Если уж писать переменную в кавычках, то так:

```
$handle = fopen("{$file}.txt", "w");
```

И, кстати, откуда вторая скобка в конце каждого варианта?

Comment: вырвал кусок кода у соседа :)

Comment: Исходя из аргумента "ведь работает":  
Чем ваш вариант отличается кроме большей читабельности?

Comment: Скажем так: так правильно :)

Comment: Ссылку на статью дай.

Comment: http://www.php.ru/manual/language.types.string.html#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Comment: Уже сам нашёл. Да в этом варианте действительно лучше через сложный синтаксис строк.

Comment: @zenith пример, вместо статьи:

> echo "ыы $tag['tag_name'] ыы";

> echo "ыы {$tag['tag_name']} ыы";

А теперь проверь, что заработает, а что нет. И сделай выводы :-)

Comment: @lampa, тут тоже можно написать без фигурных скобок и оно заработает :)

    echo "ыы $tag[tag_name] ыы";

Обрати внимание на отсутствие кавычек вокруг ключа массива

Но вариант с фигурными скобками более правильный, потому что можно использовать весьма сложные конструкции..  Типа такой:

    echo "Это значение переменной по имени, которое возвращает функция getName(): {${getName()}}";

Comment: @Photon ну я именно упор на кавычки одинарные сделал :-) С ними выдаст ошибку  T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE

Answer (score 0):

Вообще лучше переменные не писать в двойные кавычки, можно запутаться, а также это только замедляет работу сценария. Если вам нужно объединить несколько значений, можно воспользоваться конкатенацией **.** (точка) пример :

```
'./' . $file
```

Разница между

```
fopen($file, 'w');
```

и

```
fopen('./' . $file, 'w');
```

я думаю есть, но не уверен в этом, однако я точно знаю, что при написании **./** идёт обращение от папки, в которой лежит этот файл(относительно).

Comment: Минуснул, так как ничего нового не сказано.